# useEffect making infinite calls after fetching data from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm fetching a few data from my API and then I need to perform some mappings to present it in the way I need. Since API calls are not instant, I need to wait the response to update my dataset, so I did the following:

```
const workCenterResponse = useFetchWorkCenters();
const [finalDataset, setFinalDataset] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const machines = workCenterResponse.workCenterMachines.map((workCenter) => workCenter.machines.map((machine) => ({
        ...machine,
        work_center: workCenter.description
    }))).flat();

    const dataset = [
        ...machines.map((machine) => ({
                key: machine.id,
                centro: machine.work_center,
                machine: machine.code + " - " + machine.description,
                linked: true
            })
        )
    ]

    setFinalDataset(dataset);
}, [workCenterResponse]);
```

The code works this way, however the page keeps updating infinitely and I don't want this to keep happening

I already tried the following to fix this:

1. Make the `useEffect` to update only once by using `[]` instead of  `[workCenterResponse]`, doesn't work
2. Moving all the operations of flat, mapping, etc. and updating only `finalDataset` inside the `useEffect`, doesn't work
3. Using a variable `isUpdated` initialized as `false` to check if `workCenterResponse` length is greater than `1`. If so, perform the operations, update the `finalDataset` and set `isUpdated` to `true`. The `useEffect` keeps running infinitely, but will perform the operations only once. It does work properly this way, but I don't want to keep using this since it seems like a cheap fix

I don't know what to do and appreciate any suggestions

EDIT: `useFetchWorkCenters` code:

```
export function useFetchWorkCenters() {
    const [workCenters, setWorkCenters] = useState([])
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)

    async function fetchWorkCenters() {
        try {
            const response = await authApi.get('/route/api')
            setWorkCenters(response.data)
        } catch (error) {
            setError(error)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchWorkCenters()
    }, [])

    return {workCenters, error}
}
```

Comment: Why use a state and an effect at all? You want a simple variable computed from `workCenterResponse`. Or a `useMemo` at best.

Comment: @Bergi OP's code still shouldn't cause an infinite loop though

Comment: What is `useFetchWorkCenters` doing?

Comment: @Phil True. Something else must be the cause of the loop.

Comment: The spread syntax in `[...machines.map()]` is completely redundant. `Array.prototype.map()` returns a new array already

Comment: I suspect this has nothing to do with the effect hook presented here and more likely another one within `useFetchWorkCenters()`. Please [edit] your question to include that code so it contains a [mre]

Comment: @Bergi `useFetchWorkCenters` is a call to the API. I edited the question to present it

Comment: @TP95 where I am updating `workCenterRespons` inside the `useEffect`?

Comment: Something doesn't add up. There is no `workCenterMachines` property in the hook result, just `workCenters` and `error`

Comment: I would look at the parent components that this one is being used by; if the parent components are being re-constructed / rendered a bunch then that could manifest as this one being re-instantiated many times. Add lots of console.log statements to see what parts of the ui are getting re-initialized / re-rendered a bunch.

Comment: For better context, this code is to build the data to feed an Ant Design's table and I'm using Router to navigate directly to this component, the only parent it has is the Router itself.

Also, the remaining code in the file is just the `columns` data, a `handleChange` and the `return` statement with the Table div

Comment: @AkariOozora react-router-dom does have some issues where things can be unnecessarily re-rendered / re-initialized. Namely, certain hooks return unstable references that get updated whenever the location changes (even if just the query params). Even if the only parent is the main App itself I’d start adding in lots of logging statements to isolate the top-most thing getting re-rendered. Also I’ve personally been working to remove AntD stuff from my project because it is just not well written code; nothing but bugs from them.

Comment: @Phil, that object will change whenever the hook state updates (namely after the async request completes). So it should take on two distinct states as written (and then it never changes after that).

Comment: @Phil each time the hook is re-evaluated it constructs a new object to return; it’s not updating and returning the same reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is two-fold:

- the `useFetchWorkCenters()` hook is returning a *new* `{workCenters, error}` object on every render (even if neither `workCenters` nor `errors` have changed). [You don't need two states](https://react.dev/learn/choosing-the-state-structure)!
- the `useEffect` hook has this object as a dependency, as it is using it to set the `finalDataset` state, which causes a re-render. [You don't need an effect for this](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect)!

This leads to an infinite re-rendering. Fixing either would be enough to avoid the problem, but you should fix both:

```
export function useFetchWorkCenters() {
    const [result, setResult] = useState({workCenters: [], error: null});

    async function fetchWorkCenters() {
        try {
            const response = await authApi.get('/route/api');
            setResult({workCenters: response.data, error: null});
        } catch (error) {
            setResult({workCenters: result.workCenters, error});
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchWorkCenters();
    }, []);

    return result;
}
```

```
const workCenterResponse = useFetchWorkCenters();
const finalDataset = useMemo(() => {
    const machines = workCenterResponse.workCenters.flatMap(workCenter => 
        workCenter.machines.map(machine => ({
            ...machine,
            work_center: workCenter.description
        }))
    )

    return machines.map(machine => ({
        key: machine.id,
        centro: machine.work_center,
        machine: machine.code + " - " + machine.description,
        linked: true
    });
}, [workCenterResponse.workCenters]);
```

Comment: It works almost perfectly, but I still need to use `setFinalDataset` because I have to turn off `linked` sometimes and update the table. In this case, should I use a `useState` before `useMemo`?

Comment: You probably should have a separate state for storing only which machines are linked and which are not. Like `const machines = useMemo(() => workCenterResponse.workCenters.flatMap(…), [workCenterResponse.workCenters]); const linked = useState({}); const finalDataSet = machines.map(machine => ({ machine, linked: linked[machine.key] ?? true }));`